# Setting a duplicate time on a Paused HTML5 video creates a time jump or offset in the displayed frame

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I want to control a video frame-by-frame in JS. As you can control only the time in seconds of a video, it's easy to say go to frame 18 if you know the video FPS (*eg:* `18/60 = 0.3sec`, so using `video.currentTime = 0.3` does the trick).

**Problem:** 
My problem is that when playing the video with any web browser...

- First, I pause the video (regular play/pause with the video controls)
- Secondly (after a click on pause), I then run the following code `video.currentTime = video.currentTime`, you can see the video frame seems to jump backwards an extra one or two frames (object positions go back to a position that is from an earlier/previous frame.

I tested on **Firefox** (123), **Chrome** (122), and **Safari** (17.2.1).

Here is a minimal example of my problem: 
https://codepen.io/brufru/pen/XWQWpZa.

Testing process: 
(1) Click **Pause** on the HTML5 controls. 
(2) Click any white area of the page (but not on video object). 
(3) Press "t" on the keyboard (to set `video.currentTime` to itself and see a "jump" in frame pixels)

```js
//const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
const videoPlayer = document.getElementById("video-player");

var txt_currTime = document.getElementById("txt_currentTime");

videoPlayer.ontimeupdate = () => { 
  txt_currTime.innerHTML = "currentTime is: " + videoPlayer.currentTime;
}

videoPlayer.onpause = () => { 
  //alert("was paused");
}

//# page/document listens for a key press
document.onkeydown = (ke) => {
  if(ke.key === "t") 
  {
    videoPlayer.currentTime = videoPlayer.currentTime;
  }
}
```

```html
<video id="video-player" height="150" controls
src = "https://nextcloud.brunofruchard.com/index.php/s/icnrjZGPG3HmBqL/download?path=&files=" >
</video>

<br>

<p id="txt_currentTime"> Hello </p>
```

The video I am using is at 60fps, 1,5 Mb/s, and uses a key interval of 15. You can play the video, pause it, and press 't' to set currentTime to currentTime, and see that it jumps back 1-2 frames.

Does anybody have any clue what's happening here? I am **assuming there is some precision error** because of asynchronous processes, but setting `currentTime` to its value is silly, yet still does change the image displayed.